# Facebook timeline error 3502 and debug tool wont scrape localhost

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I have been testing the timeline example recipe box but when I click the botton I always get the error 3502 object at url and that its a website not a recipe.

I have tried all the answers on here and gone over all my app settings but nothing works. Also the property part of the meta links is highlighted yellow is that saying its broken?

```
meta property ="og:description" content="The Turducken of Cookies"
```

Also when I try to use the object debugger tool it always replies:

> Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.

Comment: Its a localhost one which I have tried in all different combinations of its form...

Could it be anything to do with the property part of the meta tag being displayed in a yellow box when editing in notepad2.

Comment: Maybe its because I'm using codeigniter since I have seen other localhost sites appear in the timeline, its just me who cant post from my app

Comment: You can't publish actions against localhost URLs because Facebook's crawler won't be able to read them

Comment: Can I not uhhh I wish I had seen that before wasting the last 3 days trying.

Answer (score 0):

3502 error is because of localhost as is the object debugger since facebooks crawler can't do localhost thanks Igy. The Meta tags go yellow because its highlighting its not a normal Meta tag but one facebook has created.